# Image.network overriding the border radius property flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

And after image is loaded, it is taking full container size by overriding the border radius.

This is the out put i was getting [Screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrChI.jpg)

this is the output which i was looking for
[ScreenShot2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2PAvo.jpg)

code:

```
StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                crossAxisCount: 4,
                itemCount: wallpapersList.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  String imgPath = wallpapersList[index].data['url'];
                  return Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: kSecondaryColor,
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                          Radius.circular(20),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: Image.network(imgPath, fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
                          loadingBuilder: (BuildContext context, Widget child,
                              ImageChunkEvent loadingProgress) {
                        if (loadingProgress == null) return child;
                        return Center(
                          child: SpinKitDoubleBounce(
                            color: Colors.white,
                          ),
                        );
                      }));
```

Comment: where is the progress indicator?

Comment: @jitsm555 i just updated the question again. Can you please take a look at it again. Now the problem is only image. It's it overriding the border radius property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Images don't follow the border radius of the Container.

So what you'll have to do is use ClipRRect()

Use it like this

```
Container(
child: ClipRRect(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    child: Image.network(),
  ),
),
```

Just add the ClipRRect widget and that should work.